# How to create a discord bot that uses the Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, discord, discord.js

I want to create a discord bot that can notify everyone in all my discord servers in which I have:

- Specific role
- Authority to mention everyone
- All the servers I'm in

The problem is I did check the guide here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-notification) but I didn't get it, also I don't know if it can be done dynamically like whenever I join/create a new server and have the role and invite the bot it will automatically work without updating the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your question is too large to answer here, try to ask smaller questions. However, how you would make a simple discord.js bot has been answered here:

- https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/

The documentation is here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

YouTube API's:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-api
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-node

You can attempt to learn to make a discord bot using YouTube videos and discordjs.guide, here are a few good videos that should help:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We2ijSkByw0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8k-zyUyuvlM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Np2fJOdXjE